# load partial model after ajax - mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have page containig partial views

```
  <div class="window">
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
    </div>    
    @*<div id="tlv-dialog-content" >*@
        <form id="___iskadetails">
            <div id="iska-general-details">
                @Html.Partial("_workGeneralDetails_EditForm", Model)
            </div>
        </form>
    <div id="tabstrip" class="tabstrip">
    <ul>       
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("_workDetailsDialog_Taba", "workHome"     , new { area = "work", Id = Model.Model.IskaId })">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("_workDetailsDialog_Tabb", "workHome"  , new { area = "work", Id = Model.Model.IskaId })">b</a></li>
         <li><a href="@Url.Action("_workDetailsDialog_Tabc","workHome", new { area = "work",sugId=Model.Model.SugIskaId,id = Model.Model.IskaId  })">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("_workDetailsDialog_Tabd", "workHome"    , new { area = "work", Id = Model.Model.IskaId })">d</a></li>        

    </ul>    
</div>
```

each partial in the tabstrip contain different model
i want to load the partial view after spacific ajax im doing in the client side 
in the document.ready 
what is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQUERY UI tab and load different Partial view with their model.

pls look following links that will help you.

http://kevgriffin.com/using-jquery-tabs-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views-for-ajax-goodness/

http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/jquery-ui-tabs-and-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: im using kendo ui tabs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904859/kendoui-tabstrip-htmlhelper-adding-partialviews

Comment: in this example the partial data called on the same time the main model load , i want to load the partial after spacific ajax on the client side

Comment: You are writing code in the document.ready function, it means page render when page load happens, and if you want to load partial view after some ajax then create one function which calls controller with $.ajax method to load partial view and call that function in your success response of ajax call.